# Avoid Spring ApllicationContext instanciation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I use Spring 3 to make a simple configuration.

I have an XML file called PropertyBeans.xml like that :

```
<bean id="propertyBean" class="com.myapp.PropertyBean">
    <property name="rootDirLogPath" value="C:\Users\dede" />
</bean>
```

I have the bean which match this XML and then I want to use this bean with the value injected. Actually I have :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("AppPropertyBeans.xml");
PropertyBean obj = (PropertyBean) context.getBean("propertyBean");
String rootDirLogPath = obj.getRootDirLogPath();
```

This works great but I want to know if there's a way to avoid the instantiation of ApplicationContext at each time I want to use a bean. I've heard about BeanFactory is that a good idea? Which are the others solutions?

In other words: Am I supposed to called this Application context instanciation in every Controller in spring MVC?

Comment: I think, you should first read `Spring` thoroughly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use spring beans in controllers, add line to applicationContext.xml:

```
<context:spring-configured/>
<task:annotation-driven/>
<context:component-scan base-package="by" />
```

Then write your controller following way:

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    private GroupService groupService;

        // methods with @RequestMapping annotation
}
```

This is trivial thing, so If you have questions it is strongly recommended to read "Spring in action book", chapter 7: Building web applications

Answer (score 0):

The whole idea of the ApplicationContext is that there is one (hence the name, context of the application).

So if you're creating a new one every time, you're doing it wrong.

If you use dependency injection properly, the object containing that code will already be instantiated by the injection container (Spring) and the propertyBean will have been injected.

Comment: Ok, that's why I ask it here, I know, instanciating an application every time isn't a good solution but how to avoid it with spring? Any Example, with the `@autowired`thing?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add the context as member in your class like:

```
private ApplicationContext context;
```

and instanciate it in the constructor or an init() method.

Comment: well, ok but the application context will be instanciate with each new instance of the class using it.

Comment: as Joeri Hendrickx allready pointed out, the main intension for DI ist that all is in one place. Like the Commander-Pattern. If u want it everywhere u might have a chance to implement it in the MainClass as static final member and call it from there with a getter where ever u need it. That's not pretty but might work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use `autowiring` or implements the `InitializingBean` interface.

Comment: Even with the autowiring the fist thing done in main method is the Application context instanciation. In other word, my question is how do I do this  in MVC controllers